# Impossible to find the support file 'Path/bin/Debug/File.dll.mdb'

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I want to build with MonoDevelop (on linux) an application which I've done with Visual Studio (on Windows).

All subprojects of my solution build correctly but at the end of the build, I finally get the following error:
**Unable to find the support file 'Path/bin/Debug/File.dll.mdb'**.

In fact, I never needed of this file to build my solution on Windows. Therefore, this file doesn't exist in the directory bin/Debug. I only find DLL or PDB files in that directory.

How could I correct it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The mdb files are the Mono equivalents of pdb files in .NET, and if you do a debug build in Mono (Project settings -> Build -> Compiler -> Debug information: Full), you should end up getting mdb files.

Comment: What is your version number of MonoDevelop ? Is it still available in the version 4.0.12 (mine) ? I don't find the option Debug Information ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found !

Go to the menu: Edit > Preferences > Projects > Build > Compile projects using MSBuild/XBuild (experimental).

Thank you.